# 2d Array: Changing Elements Perl

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array in Perl. I passed the array to a subroutine and I want to modify all elements of the 2d array then return it and print the array. I have attached my code so far below. The problem I am having is actually changing each individual element and passing the array to a subroutine.

Original Matrix+Code

```
       x            y       z
CG  -3.74900 -4.89100 -3.45400 
OD1 -6.45900 -6.29100 -6.08000 
OD2 -1.31600 -1.83300 -0.17600   

sub translateMatrixOperation
{
my (@translatematrix, $x, $y, $z) = @_;
print "PRINTING FIRST\n";
my $arrsize = scalar @translatematrix;
for(my $i = 0; $i <= $arrsize; $i++)
{
    for(my $j = 0; $j <= $arrsize; $j++)
    {
        if ($j == 0)
        {
            print "[$i][$j]:$translatematrix[$i][$j]\n";
            $_ = $_ - $x;
        }
        elsif ($j == 1)
        {
            print "[$i][$j]:$translatematrix[$i][$j]\n";
           $_ = $_ - $y;
        }
        elsif ($j == 2)
        {
            print "[$i][$j]:$translatematrix[$i][$j]\n";
            $_ = $_ - $z;
        }
    }
}
print "PRINTING\n";
for(my $i = 0; $i <= $arrsize; $i++)
{
    for(my $j = 0; $j <= $arrsize; $j++)
    {
        print "$translatematrix[$i][$j] ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
# return (\@translatematrix);
```

}
I want to edit the whole array by adding a constant value to the x values, a constant value to the y values, and a constant to the z. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: regarding style, `for(my $i = 0; $i <= $arrsize; $i++)` is commonly written as `for my $i (0 .. $#arr)` for `@arr` array

Comment: Did you consider using [PDL](http://pdl.perl.org/)? Should make matrix operations very easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my (@translatematrix, $x, $y, $z) = @_;
```

does not make sense as `@translatematrix` slurps all elements from `@_`, and should be:

```
my ($translatematrix, $x, $y, $z) = @_;
```

where `$translatematrix` is array reference.

```
        $_ = $_ - $x;
```

should be more like

```
$translatematrix->[$i][$j] -= $x;
```

and also similar logic to `$y` and `$z` should be applied.

Comment: This technique works, but it prevents me from using the current method of calculating length. How do I calculate length of the array?

Comment: @user2657817 you can change parameter order ie. `my ($x, $y, $z, @translatematrix) = @_;` so array is last one